# Prevent mouse-selected text from being put into Emacs paste buffer?

Tags: emacs, editor, cua-mode

In emacs, there is a feature where if I select text with a mouse, then without pressing
`ctrl-c` I can paste into emacs with ctrl-v if I have cua mode turned on.

I want to turn off this feature while keeping the cua mode on. I mean I want to 
explicitly press ctrl-c so that the text will get copied to the clipboard.

Comment: Does it only affect the CUA bindings or the normal yanking (pasting) as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are using a version of Emacs older than version 24? If so, see the last paragraph of [this page of the current Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html#Clipboard). You can probably get rid of the behaviour you dislike by setting `x-select-enable-primary` to `nil`.

From my quick tests, setting it to `T` (which isn't the default on Emacs 24) reproduces the problem behaviour, and this happens both in and not in `cua-mode`.

Comment: For future reference: On Unixes the "old-fashioned" way to copy text between applications was the primary selection, which behaved a bit like the clipboard, and was filled by selecting text with a mouse. Once you've switched off yanking from it, you'll still be able to insert its contents with a middle mouse click, which can be very useful!